# ActiveRecord :through to set default values on through table

Tags: ruby, activerecord

I would like to set a default value in a has_many through association.

Lets say I have three models:

People

Friends

Dogs

A person can request that a dog becomes their friend.

So a person would create an association where friends has an active column = false.

```
User
  has_many :friends
  has_many :dogs, :through => :friends
```

Now when I assign a dog to a user

```
User.find(1).dogs << dog
```

The friends table has null in the active column.

My friends model is defined as

```
Friend
  def initialize(args = {})
    super(args)
    active = false
  end
```

yet this does not work because the friend object is never created. Do I have to manually create one?

Comment: I don't think it's possible, in your case, to have a `dog` without having a `friend`.

Comment: What happens when you save the User object?

Comment: Incorrect understanding. I want to create a dog, and a friend, but I want the friend's active flag to be set to false. The friend's active flag will be set to null as the save happens. I can set the default value in the database to be false, but was lookng for a ruby-solution. Also am I just doing the models incorrectly? Is there a different pattern for doing these active/inactive relationships, like friendships that have to be approved from both sides?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set default values of a model; In the model I do this

```
    before_save :default_values

    private
    def default_values
      self.status = :active unless self.status
    end
```

Not sure if this is the correct approach though.

Answer (score 1):

With the following code you'll create a new `friend` with `active = false`

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :friends, :conditions => "active = false"
  has_many :dogs, :through => :friends
end

@user = User.new
@user.friends.create #or @user.friends.build
```

Comment: I can't really do that because I need the other values for active for other reasons. I feel Ram's answer is a bit better suited.